# grub wont let go of my hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, grub

how can i delete the place that contains grub files?

i tried the below:

deleted all the partitions of the hard disk twice:

1. using Acronis Disk Director Suite 10
2. windows 8 installer.

i have also removed the bios battery because i read in a thread that the bios might be the problem.

yet it still says:

```
no such partition
grub rescue>
```

right now i'm wiping the hard disk using Acronis Disk Director Suite.

Comment: If you're wiping the disk, you lost Grub

Comment: finally, after about 5% of wiping the hard disk, i canceled the operation and restart my pc.... and it did actually gone :D

Answer (score 1):

Grub is stored in the boot loader.  You need to zero the first 32k of your disk (immediately after the MBR), or possibly at the start of your partition.   If you zero the first 512 bytes of your file system layout and the systems ability to boot grub - you can do this under Linux by doing a dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/DISKNAME bs=512 count=1

A more generic answer is to get your OS to recreate the MBR of the disk.  This will vary between OS's, but I vaguely recall FDISK /mbr under DOS/old versions of Windows, and I believe "fixmbr" for newer versions of Windows.